# two issues on the lazy instantiation in the Singleton pattern

Tags: python-3.x, class, singleton

My python version:

```
python3 --version
Python 3.9.2
```

Issue 1:
What does `isinstance` function mean?

```
class Singleton1(object):
    __instance = None
    def __init__(self):
        if not hasattr(Singleton1, '__instance'):
            print("__init__ method called, but no instance created")
        else:
            print("instance already created:", self.__instance)
    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls):
        if not cls.__instance:
            cls.__instance = Singleton1()
        return cls.__instance
```

Initialize it :

```
x = Singleton1()
__init__ method called, but no instance created
```

Have a check with `isinstance` function:

```
isinstance(x,Singleton1)
True
```

If x is not an instance,why does `isinstance(x,Singleton1)` say it is an instance of Singleton1?

Issue2:
Why `__init__` method can't be called anyway?

Now repalce all `__instance` (double underscores) with `_instance`(single underscore) in the class `Singleton1` and replace all `Singleton1` with `Singleton2`:

```
class Singleton2(object):
    _instance = None
    def __init__(self):
        if not hasattr(Singleton2, '_instance'):
            print("__init__ method called, but no instance created")
        else:
            print("instance already created:", self._instance)
    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = Singleton2()
        return cls._instance
```

Initialize it:

```
y = Singleton2()
instance already created: None
```

Why `__init__` method can't be called anyway in this status?

@snakecharmerb on issue1,Why someone say it is lazy instantiation ,if isinstance(x,Singleton1) is true,it is no need to call with Singleton1.get_instance() ,because the instance is already created during instantiation.

Comment: may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hasattr` check does not do what you think it does.  Using `Singleton2`<sup>*</sup>, `hasattr(Singleton2, '_instance')` is always `True`, because the class has an attribute named `_instance`.  You want to check the *value* of the instance, so use getattr instead; then the expected output will be printed.

The `isinstance` checks succeed because `Singleton2()` will return a new instance each time - there is nothing to prevent this.  You can add a `__new__` method to create `_instance` and return it every time `Singleton2()` is called.  Note that this will mean that `_instance` will always exist by the time `__init__` is called.

```py
class Singleton2:

    _instance = None     
       
    def __new__(cls):    
        if cls._instance is not None:    
            return cls._instance    
        instance = super().__new__(cls)    
        cls._instance = instance    
        return instance
```

---

<sup>*</sup> The `hasattr` check in `Singleton1` is complicated by the name-mangling performed on `__instance`.  In general, avoid using double-underscored variable names, except for avoiding name clashes in class hierarchies.

Comment: How about the first question?

Comment: How do you mean?  `x` is an instance of the class, so `isinstance` returns `True`.  Do you think it should not?

Comment: Why someone say it is lazy instantiation ,if `isinstance(x,Singleton1)` is true,it is no need to call with  `Singleton1.get_instance()` ,because the instance is already created during instantiation.

Comment: The purpose of the singleton design pattern is that there should only ever be one instance of the class, so instantiating the class should always return _the same instance_.  The implementation in the question is lazy in the sense that the instance is not created until `get_instance()` is called.  The ability to bypass `get_instance()` by instantiating the class directly is a defect in the implementation.  I've demonstrated one way to fix this using `__new__`.  See also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6760685/5320906) for other ways to create singletons in Python.

Comment: I got a clear conclusion that it can't create a lazy instantiation with my two methods,is that true or not?

Comment: Yes - your class only works as a singleton if instances are always produces by calling `get_instance()` - if `Singleton()` is called then a new instance is produced instead the instance cached in `_instance`.